# Space deformation retracts to a point.

Tags: algebraic-topology, proof-verification, homotopy-theory

If space $X$ deformation retracts to a point $x\in X$, then for each open $U\in X$ containing $x$ there exists an open $V\in U$ again containing $x$ s.t. inclusion of $V$ into $U$ is nullhomotopic.

My attempt:
Since $X$ deformation retracts to a point $x$, there is a corresponding map $F:X\times I \to X$. So restriction of this map could be a solution. I suppose, the restriction of this maps domain to the set $V=pr_{X}\left(F^{-1}(U)\right)$ would be the right choice.

My geometrical understanding of this problem is next: We have to find a neighbourhood $V$ of $x$ s.t. at any time $t$ its points do not "get out" from the neighbourhood $U$. In other words the $F(V\times I) \subset U$.

Does my idea make sense? Would you correct anything if it does?

Comment: Yes, this does make perfect sense. To resolve the geometric problem you have, note that you need to fine a $V \times I$ which is contained in $F^{-1}(U)$  and contain $\{x_0\} \times I$. Have you heard of the tube lemma?

Comment: @BalarkaSen Isn't just taking $V=pr_X\left(F^{-1}(U)\right)$ enough? Or is it wrong that $f(V\times I) \subset U $ ?

Comment: Restricting $F$ to some $V \times I$ you only get a map $F : V \times I \to X$. You have to pick $V$ so that the image fits in $U \subset X$. $F^{-1}(U)$ would merely be a subspace of $X \times I$. You can project to $X$ by the projection map $X \times I \to X$, but how can you guarantee that the resulting $V$ you have will be such that $V \times I \subset F^{-1}(U)$?

Comment: For example, geometrically, image of $F^{-1}(U)$ by the projection $X \times I \to X$ is the same as taking the largest possible section of $F^{-1}(U)$. That $V \times I$ is going to contain $F^{-1}(U)$, i.e., $F^{-1}(U) \subset V \times I$, but not the other way around!

Comment: oh, I see. Thank you, I'll try to fix it.

Comment: You need to use the tube lemma. I can post an answer if you want, but if you want to figure it out on your own, no problem. I encourage that.

Comment: Don't need answer yet. I'll ask for hints if I stuck badly. I'll try to solve it